# CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo Causing incorrect format error

Tags: c#, formatexception

Everytime when I type in z as a input it fails. I don't understand what the problem is. It get the error " System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format" Dsales is a interger going into the converter to get converted into dollar and cents. Whats not correct about that?

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
class HomeSales
{
   static void Main()
   {
    string response;
    int dsales = 0;
    int esales = 0;
    int fsales = 0;
    int initial;
    string damount;
    string eamount;
    string famount;
    int damounti;
    int eamounti;
    int famounti;
    

WriteLine ("Enter a salesperson initial");
response = ReadLine();
//initial = Convert.ToInt32(response);

while (response == "d" || response == "D")
{
  WriteLine ("Enter Line of sale");
  damount = ReadLine();
  damounti = Convert.ToInt32(damount);
  dsales = dsales + damounti;
  
}

while (response == "z" || response == "Z")

{
  WriteLine("Danielle sold {0}", dsales.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
}
   }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? I can only assume it is the `Convert.ToInt32(damount)`, are you sure that `damount` contains an integer?

Comment: Try converting your int to a double, int shouldn't really be used to represent monetary value. You can see at the following microsoft ref, their example uses double https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types

Comment: david g... damount is the string that the user typed in. I converted it to a int in the line below it. So damounti is the int version. I get the error when i type z. so it is the culture info line that is giving me the error. dsales is a int. what is the problem?

Comment: Dub Dub... i changed dsales to a double and i changed damounti to a double and i changed the convert to int to convert to double. I still get the same error

Comment: Debug your code line by line, check the value when you run it. Show us only the line of code that gives you the error and the values that you pass into it.

Comment: The problem is the way you have written your code. You initially enter the first `while` loop but you never break out of it. So, I think you press `z`, expecting to enter the 2nd loop, but you are actually in the first loop and trying to convert `z` to `int`. So, refactor your code, it doesn't work. Basically I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: so if the first loop going works while it equals d or D. so why would it go back into that loop if response = z

Comment: @RickyBascom: How would you expect the response ever to become "z"? Once you've entered *either* of your `while` loops, they'll keep going forever (or until an exception is thrown) because you never change the value of `response` within the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You have incorrectly programmed your console loop.

Judging from your variable declarations and strings, your code intends to record sales amounts for different salespeople, reporting the total sale amount when sale entries are done.

The `FormatException` comes when you type "z" after the "Enter Line of Sale" prompt.

Instead of assuming that the user will always type a valid number, add a condition to check for a valid input before attempting to parse a number. The conditional check should also include the means to exit the loop early, or to at least avoid the code that parses a numerical value.

Also, as you're dealing with values interpreted as currency, consider using the System.Decimal (`decimal`) structure to store values, as calculations would be more accurate.

Comment: This is not an/the answer. Please read the comments on the post !